# Allow Apache to execute git pull

Tags: php, git, shell, webhooks

Haven't been able to figure this out yet.. I've seen a few answers around but none of them help.

I'm trying to use Github Webhooks to have github hit a url on my server and have the server pull down newly committed items as soon as that hits. I have a php script with the following:

```
<?php `git pull git@github.com:my-user/myrepo.git`; ?>
```

However that script when hit is run as user `apache` so I tried:

```
chown -R apache:apache .
```

and it still has a permission denied error.

So then I tried editing the sudoers file and changing the following:

```
Host_Alias      LOCAL=127.0.0.1
apache          LOCAL=NOPASSWD: /var/www/html/git-hook.php
```

and that still doesn't work.

How can this be accomplished? If I run:

```
 sudo php git-hook.php
```

it works just fine so nothing is wrong with the code in the php file. I just want that to be automated.

Any ideas?

**Edit:**

I also forgot to mention. I even created a folder `/home/apache/.ssh` and copied the public key for the git pull over and same result.

Comment: <?php \`sudo git pull git@github.com:my-user/myrepo.git\`; ?> with apache user in sudoers?  Its git sudo is running (via PHP), not git-hook.php

Comment: Yields the same result. Not sure I understand the last part of your comment "Its git sudo is running (via PHP), not git-hook.php"

Comment: I was meaning rather than running php as root which runs git, run php as apache which runs git as root (so you would need to edit the `/var/www/html/git-hook.php` line in your sudoers).  Anything that sheds more light in apache error log?

Comment: Modified my sudoers file to `apache  LOCAL=NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/php` and now I'm receiving from logs `sudo: sorry, you must have a tty to run sudo` additionally I'm seeing an odd set of: `Could not create directory '/var/www/.ssh'.
Host key verification failed.
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly`

Comment: Should it not be `apache LOCAL=NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/git` - the command that the `apache` user can run via `sudo`?

Comment: same result `sudo: sorry, you must have a tty to run sudo`

Comment: Do you have `Default requiretty` in your suoders?

Comment: Yes I just disabled it. I'm now receiving the following:  `sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified
Sorry, try again.
sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified
Sorry, try again.
sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified
Sorry, try again.
sudo: 3 incorrect password attempts` seems my NOPASSWD isn't firing correctly.

Comment: Is your apache user defiantly called `apache` and not `www-data`?

Comment: Yes, at the top of my git pull php script I have echo ``whoami`;` and it's returning apache.

Comment: Just to debug, change suoders to `apache ALL = NOPASSWD: ALL` and try again.  I would also try calling something other than git via sudo in your PHP and see what that does.  The no tty present errors can be related to the called program as well as sudo.

Comment: `ALL = NOPASSWD: ALL` worked.

Comment: Figured it out. Changing it to `ALL = NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/git` fixed it.. the host alias must have been broken.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18617/discussion-between-didster-and-peter)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your PHP to run git via sudo

```
<?php `sudo git pull git@github.com:my-user/myrepo.git`; ?>
```

Then change your suoders to allow git to be run by the apache user

```
apache ALL = NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/git
```

Comment: If git pull command has to run as apache user, how it will authorize because, ssh auth will work only when you do things from respective user?

Answer (score 1):

There are already Git Wrappers and librarys. Maybe you can try one of them:
https://github.com/kbjr/Git.php and/or http://www.gitphp.org/projects/gitphp/wiki

Comment: Seems quite a bit overkill for what I need. I only need the ability to execute a simple git pull command, and only when Github hits the server with the webhook.

Answer (score 0):

I did this for a dev site -- i wouldnt advise this  for a prd site although i cant think of anything particularly dangerous about it provided the scripts dont take parameters..

I created a php script that does a git pull.  In the web browser I navigate to that script and any changes pushed by deisgners etc are automatically deployed.
`http://.../gitpullscript/gitpullscript.php`

This works by creating a git checkout that the apache user owns.  You do this by creating a directory somewhere outside the document root belongs to the apache user (www-data in this case).  Then a git clone into that directory, so all the files belong to www-data.  afterwards soft link the directories i want into my document root so they can be accessed ni the web browser.

www-data is not in the git group, and the repositories are setup so that everyone can read (but not write)..   therefore www-data can pull but not push

in the project heirarchy I created a directory to hold the gitpull script..  I use .htaccess to password protect this dir.

`<?php exec('cd /var/www-data/projects/myrepo; git pull');`

`mkdir /var/www-data
sudo chown www-data-www-data
su www-data
mkdir /var/www-data/projects
cd /var/www-data/projects
git clone my-repo`